# Twitter ( php ) - como obter imagem do usuário e o email q este usuário usa na rede social

Tags: twitter-api

Não estou conseguindo achar na documentação se esses dados podem ser acessados ou não. A documentação (na minha opinião) é muito superficial em relação a documentação do SDK do Facebook. 
estou usando o OAuth como manda a documentação. A integração (php) já foi feita e com sucesso.
Desde de já agradeço ! :)

Answer (score 1):

O Twitter **não libera acesso ao e-mail do usuário**, logo você não será capaz de obter essa informação a partir da `API` do Twitter. Em vez disso, você tem que obter essa informação no formulário de inscrição.

```
// a lib necessárias
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

// define suas configurações de acesso
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "SEU_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "SEU_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET",
    'consumer_key' => "SEU_CONSUMER_KEY",
    'consumer_secret' => "SEU_CONSUMER_SECRET"
);

// escolha a url que você precisa da documentação, essa é a users/show
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json';

// o método de requisição, de acordo com a documentação é GET e não POST
$requestMethod = 'GET';

// definindo sua string
$getfield = '?screen_name=j7mbo';

// criando o objeto
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

// faz a requisição e obtem a resposta dentro da variável $json
$json =  $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                 ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                 ->performRequest();

// transforma tudo para um array json
$result = json_decode($json);

// mostrando/acessando a profile_image_url
echo $result->profile_image_url;
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento Paulo Costa !

Comment: O $getfield = '?screen_name=j7mbo'; é nome do meu usuario ? Outra questão :
Estou testando no localhost e ta dando problema de SSL :  
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SSL certificate problem: 
unable to get local issuer certificate' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\socialplugins\signin-twitter\twitter-api-php\TwitterAPIExchange.php:296 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\socialplugins\signin-twitter\twitter-api-php\index.php(31): 
TwitterAPIExchange->performRequest() #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\socialplugins\signin-twitter\twitter-api-php\TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 296.

Comment: o que pode estar gerando este erro ?